# latex: how to center-align chapter titles in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I am trying to center-align chapter titles in the table of contents. I tried using \centering in the preamble but it did not work:

```
\makeatletter
\let\stdl@chapter\l@chapter
\renewcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{%
    \stdl@chapter{\centering\textcolor{blue}{#1}}{\centering{#2}}}
```

Here is a complete example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\makeatletter
\let\stdl@chapter\l@chapter
\renewcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{%
    \stdl@chapter{\centering{#1}}{\centering{#2}}}
\let\stdl@section\l@section
\renewcommand*{\l@section}[2]{%
  \stdl@section{{#1}}{{#2}}}
\let\stdl@subsection\l@subsection
\renewcommand*{\l@subsection}[2]{%
  \stdl@subsection{{#1}}{{#2}}}
\makeatother
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter one}
\section{Section One}
\subsection{Subsection One}
\subsection{Subsection Two}
\section{Section Two}
\subsection{Subsection One}
\subsection{Subsection Two}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still want the chapter number left aligned and only the title centered, then renew `\cftchapaftersnumb`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnumb{\hfill}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter one}
\section{Section One}
\subsection{Subsection One}
\subsection{Subsection Two}
\section{Section Two}
\subsection{Subsection One}
\subsection{Subsection Two}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Modifying `\l@chapter`, instead, as the OP was attempting, will have an effect on the chapter number, as well:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tocloft}
%\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnumb{\hfill}
\makeatletter
\let\stdl@chapter\l@chapter
\renewcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{\stdl@chapter{\hfill#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter one}
\section{Section One}
\subsection{Subsection One}
\subsection{Subsection Two}
\section{Section Two}
\subsection{Subsection One}
\subsection{Subsection Two}
\end{document}
```

[image]