# Chapter number above chapter name / table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I'm trying to set my table of contents using the `tocloft` package (using [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462505/latex-how-to-center-align-chapter-titles-in-the-table-of-contents) as a guide) to get something like this:
[image]
And this is what I've done so far

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paperheight=210mm,paperwidth=170mm,left=2cm,right=1.78cm,top=2.03cm,bottom=1.95cm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\makeatletter
\let\stdl@chapter\l@chapter
\renewcommand*{\l@chapter}[1]{\stdl@chapter{\hfill\underline{#1}}{}}
\makeatother
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Hello}

\section{Hi}

\chapter{Goodbye}

\section{See you soon}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want the chapter number twice: in roman as I and in arabic as 1.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does what I think you want.

```
% tocchapprob.tex SE 634861

\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paperheight=210mm,paperwidth=170mm,left=2cm,right=1.78cm,top=2.03cm,bottom=1.95cm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\makeatletter
%\let\stdl@chapter\l@chapter
%\renewcommand*{\l@chapter}[1]{\stdl@chapter{\hfill\underline{#1}}{}}
\makeatother
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

%% eventually the number of the next chapter
\newcounter{nextchap}

%% set nextchap to the number of the next chapter
\newcommand{\incchap}{\setcounter{nextchap}{\value{chapter}}\addtocounter{nextchap}{1}}

%% add centered Chapter number into the ToC
%\newcommand{\addchaptoc}{\addtocontents{toc}{%
%    \vspace{\baselineskip}\centering \underline{\textbf{Chapter \Roman{nextchap}}}\par}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

% get the number of the next chapter
\incchap
% add centered Chapter number into the ToC
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{\baselineskip}\centering \underline{\textbf{Chapter \Roman{nextchap}}}\par}
\chapter{Hello}

\section{Hi}

Sectional text.


Nextchap is \thenextchap, and chapter is \thechapter.

\incchap
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{\baselineskip}\centering \underline{\textbf{Chapter \Roman{nextchap}}}\par}
\chapter{Goodbye}

Nextchap is \thenextchap, and chapter is \thechapter.


\section{See you soon}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You could, perhaps, make the user interface a little simpler, but that is up to you.

**EDIT** If you wanted dot leaders between the chapter titles and page numbers then add `\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep}` into your preamble.